# How to say that there is no peas? Countable or Uncountable?

Tags: grammar

Since the vegetable 'peas' can be countable and uncountable, which of the following is correct:

There isn't any peas.

There aren't any peas.

Comment: The second. Peas are a countable noun. Unless you have as many peas as the countless sands of the seas ...

Comment: @MoziburUllah Even then they are countable, the difference is that a non-count noun requires a unit before we can discuss it in a count sense. I can't normally say "I have six sands on my shoe" or "The builder's merchant has left two sands on my drive" but I can say "I have six _grains_ of sand on my shoe" or "The builder's merchant has left two tonnes of sand on my drive". We can, however, say "I have twenty peas on my plate" (count usage) or "I have two spoonfuls of peas on my plate" (non count usage).

Comment: @BoldBen: Not when there "aren't any peas". Your commebt is directed at a question that hasn't been asked ...

Comment: @MoziburUllah The question doesn't make any difference to my point which is that you said that peas, as a word, was not countable if you had as many peas as the (grains) of sand in the sea. The fact that the number of peas are too many to count doesn't make 'peas' an uncountable noun. You could take a spoonful of them, count the peas in the sample, and say 'there are twenty peas here' without using a unit. You can't do that with sand unless you are talking about types or colours of sand. My builders merchant could have left me sharp and soft sand. I'd have two sands but wouldn't know how much.

Comment: @BoldBen: I was commenting on the question even if you aren't. If you reread your comment above you **don't** address the second part of my conment because you start with, **'even then they are countable'** and you go in that vein right to the end of the comment.

Comment: Does the same refer to lentils and beans too? We should say and write: There aren't any lentils. There aren't any beans. Lentils and beans are countable.

Comment: @MoziburUllah It is the second part of your first comment that I disagree with. It doesn't matter how many countable items you have, even if they are as impossible to count as the stars in the universe, the noun naming them is still a countable noun. The second part of your first comment says that "peas" becomes a non-count noun when there are enough peas to make counting them impossible. That just is not true.

Answer (score 1):

The question is based upon a false assumption:

> Since the vegetable 'peas' can be countable and uncountable,

Absent an example of "pea" as uncountable, the question fails.

*There......is........n't...................{any peas}.

Adverb...verb negation {plural noun phrase as subject}

In English, the verb and subject agree in number.

There **are**n't any **peas**. - Correct.

Comment: Please explain the use of "absent"

Comment: @Anton OED **absent**, *preposition* -- Etymon: absent adj. = **In the absence of, without.** -- 2006   Daily Tel. 17 Mar. 23/3   *An Australian republic is not only not inevitable, but, absent some calamity, it will never come to pass.*

Comment: Seems sensible. I never met that construction before. I would have use "Lacking an example ..." or "Without an example ..." but have no difficulty with your version. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

This is not as trivial a question as some will suppose. I suggest that some insight comes from thinking about meanings as sets. I shall denote the sets that represent meanings by {}.

Let us start with the two statements that cover all possibilities of there being one or more peas: "*There are peas*" and "*There is a pea*". I have omitted "*any*" because it adds nothing to the analysis. The singular statement about a countable noun requires the indefinite article “*a*”.

How do we logically and **consistently** develop the negatives of these statements?

Consider the development of the negative of “*There are peas*”.

> *There are peas*
>
> *There are {peas}*
>
> *There are {not {peas}}*
>
> But *{not {peas}}* = *{no peas}* and hence:
>
> *There are {no peas}*
>
> "*There are no peas*"

In the same way, start from the singular version that applies to a countable noun such as pea, a version that requires the indefinite article “*a*”: “*There is a pea*”.

> *There is a pea*
>
> *There is {a pea}*
>
> *There is {not {a pea}}*
>
> But *{not {a pea}}* = *{no pea}* and hence:
>
> *There is {no pea}*
>
> "*There is no pea*"

In this way we have developed **consistently** all necessary negatives of the two original statements. We have covered all cases of presence and absence of one or more peas. Therefore no further constructions need be sought.

Furthermore, the development of a negative such as “*There is not peas*” from the original *"There are peas"* "requires inconsistent development of the negatives of the original plural and singular statements.

From this viewpoint I argue that your second statement is correct and the first incorrect.

Comment: I rather expected this answer to attract adverse comment from those who don't care for the application of set logic to language. And such has proved to be the case. I regret their not having explained themselves.